# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Can't get wireless working on Dell latitude d620

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I was trying to get Ubuntu working on old laptop. I believed it's wireless driver issue.

Output from a couple of commands:

```
myhost@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:    precise 

myhost@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grp Network
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)


myhost@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Then I google it and found article to reinstall wireless driver 
at [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

So I did command `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` (Done)
and command `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` (Error as below lines)

```
...
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-29-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.8.0-29-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-29-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl
```

Any suggestion to fix it? Thanks First.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please get a working ethernet connection temporarily and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and give us your report.

Comment: About 1 hour ago, I plugged in network and did as your suggestion to remove and install. There was an crash report during this install of linux-firmware-nonfree.

On screen it had a title: Crash report

Package:
   bcmwl-kernel-source (not installed)
Problem Type:
   Package
Title:
   bcmwl-kernel-source 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0utbuntu0.0.1:bcmwl kernel module failed to build
ApportVersion:
   2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4
Architecture:
   amd64
DKMSBuildLog:
   3.8.0-29-generic
Date:
   Mon Aug 26 02:46:48 2013
...

Comment: Please try one at a time and give me the results: sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source  I will have further suggestions after I hear your report.

Comment: Chili555, I did the remove command again. Below lines are from Terminal output. //--- 
myhost@ubuntu:~$ 
myhost@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for myhost: 
正在讀取套件清單... 完成
正在重建相依關係          
正在讀取狀態資料... 完成
套件 bcmwl-kernel-source 並沒有被安裝，所以也不會被移除
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  dkms
使用 'apt-get autoremove' 來將其移除。
升級 0 個，新安裝 0 個，移除 0 個，有 0 個未被升級。
myhost@ubuntu:~$ ^C
//--- If it will help, I can change default locale. Thanks

Comment: So far, so good! Next, please do: sudo apt-get autoremove. If that goes successfully, next do: sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

Comment: Chili555,

I did the autoremove command successfully.
Next command to install linux-firmware and no crash report this time.
It says install linux-firmware already is the newest version.
With Upgrade 0, New installation 0, Remove 0, Not Upgrade 0
What is next suggestion ?

Terminal Output as below:
// ----------
myhost@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for myhost: 
正在讀取套件清單... 完成
正在重建相依關係          
正在讀取狀態資料... 完成
下列套件將會被【移除】：
  dkms
升級 0 個，新安裝 0 個，移除 1 個，有 0 個未被升級。
此操作完成之後，會空出 348 kB 的磁碟空間。
是否繼續進行 [Y/n]？y

Comment: continue ... （正在讀取資料庫 ... 146955 files and directories currently installed.)
正在移除 dkms ...
正在進行 man-db 的觸發程式 ...
myhost@ubuntu:~$ 
myhost@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
正在讀取套件清單... 完成
正在重建相依關係          
正在讀取狀態資料... 完成
linux-firmware-nonfree 已經是最新版本了。
升級 0 個，新安裝 0 個，移除 0 個，有 0 個未被升級。
myhost@ubuntu:~$

Comment: Now load the correct driver: sudo modprobe b43. Does your wireless work now? Is the wireless switch set to enable wireless? rfkill list all Are there any helpful messages here? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43

Comment: Chili555,

Yes, It's working. My WiFi light is on after yor suggestion of modprobe command.
I have two more questions. 
Q1: Why the autoremove then install linux-firmeare-nofree didn't have crash report this time?
Q2: How do I discount wire and connect to my SSID with password?
Thanks a lot.   

// ---
myhost@ubuntu:~$ 
myhost@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe b43
[sudo] password for myhost: 
myhost@ubuntu:~$ 
// WiFi light is on
myhost@ubuntu:~$
myhost@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all

Comment: 0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
myhost@ubuntu:~$ 
myhost@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43
[11639.156737] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)
[11639.200091] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 4, Type 2 (G), Revision 8
[11639.732075] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[11639.821179] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[11639.822187] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
myhost@ubuntu:~$

Comment: I do not know why there wasn't a crash. The package that was autoremoved, dkms, has nothing to do with b43 and linux-firmware-nonfree. Detach the ethernet and click the Network Manager icon at the top right. You should see a list of networks to connect to. Click yours and a prompt for your WPA2 password should appear. If your question is solved, please accept my answer. http://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu%284%29.png

Comment: Chili55, A quick question: How does Ubuntu auto do "sudo modprobe b43" after reboot - just want to auto to have wireless connection via WiFi. :) ?

Comment: Chili55, I saw an article to suggest "Slow or Erratic Wi-Fi in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? " Should install Wicd package if it can help my auto-connect issue.

Comment: To get b43 to load on boot, do these commands in sequence: sudo -i; echo b43 >> /etc/modules; exit.

Comment: I doubt you need Wicd.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am happy with wireless connection. I don't know what to do with the link in answer.eui.eu you provided.

Comment: Chili55, I click on link at http://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu%284%29.png And all I got is a PNG image. Didn't see Accept button. Maybe you can help more to resolve my request that you have been helping.

Comment: Please see here about accepting my answer: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer